# Order results by weighted variables?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sorting, rails-activerecord

I have a listing of ~10,000 apps and I'd like to order them by certain columns, but I want to give certain columns more "weight" than others.

For instance, each app has `overall_ratings` and `current_ratings`. If the app has a lot of `overall_ratings`, that's worth 1.5, but the number of `current_ratings` would be worth, say 2, since the number of `current_ratings` shows the app is active and currently popular.

Right now there are probably 4-6 of these variables I want to take into account.

So, how can I pull that off? In the query itself? After the fact using just Ruby (remember, there are over 10,000 rows that would need to be processed here)? Something else?

This is a Rails 3.2 app.

Comment: SQL database is not the best tool for the job here. Introduce elasticsearch to your stack and you're golden.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting 10000 objects in plain Ruby doesn't seem like a good idea, specially if you just want the first 10 or so.

You can try to put your math formula in the query  (using the order method from Active Record).

However, my favourite approach would be to create a float attribute to store the score and update that value with a before_save method.

I would read about dirty attributes so you only perform this scoring when some of you're criteria is updated.

You may also create a rake task that re-scores your current objects.

This way you would keep the scoring functionality in Ruby (you could test it easily) and you could add an index to your float attribute so database queries have better performance.

Comment: +1 for keeping a running score, although if it ever needs to be "graded on a curve" it'll take a bit more effort.

Answer (score 0):

One attempt would be to let the DB do this work for you with some query like: (can not really test it because of laking db schema):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT *, 
                                         (2*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM overall_ratings
                                         WHERE app_id = a.id) + 
                                          1.5*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM current_ratings
                                         WHERE app_id = a.id) 
                                       AS rating FROM apps a 
                                       WHERE true HAVING rating > 3 ORDER BY rating desc")
```

Idea is to sum the number of ratings found for each current and overall rating with the subqueries for an specific app id and weight them as desired.